# Selecting text files according to numbers on an array?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm making a quiz. First it sorts 15 numbers in a random order for loading each question. For instance, a possible loading for the questions could be 7,3,5,6, and so on. I want to change the 4 options on a combobox according to the current question, loading the text from a specific .txt file on a directory.

For example, if I'm on question number 7, I want to load the text from here:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\q7.txt
```

Inside `q7.txt` there are 4 lines with the different possible answers the user can choose for question 7:

```
"option 1"
"option 2"
"option 3"
"option 4"
```

How can I code this so in my combobox i get

```
"option 1"
"option 2"
"option 3"
"option 4"
```

as my options?

Comment: What language are you working in?  You should add that tag :)

Comment: vb.net, i'm new here sorry

Comment: we aren't going to do it for you. provide some code and we will help you

Answer (score 0):

A way can be:

1. Build the filePath String dinamically, ie. pass the question number and build the right filePath string.
2. Read strings in the file and add them into a List.
3. Set the List as the DataSource of the combobox.

---

```
Sub Main
    Dim answers = GetAnswers(1)
    For Each item In answers
        console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetAnswers(questionNr As Integer) As String()
    Return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(BuildFileString(questionNr))
End Function

Private Function BuildFileString(questionNr As Integer) As String
    Return $"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\q{questionNr}.txt"
End Function
```